# How can i get cookie value in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, cookies

I am setting cookie in in blade file using javascript by below piece of code

```
function showPosition(position) {
    var lat=position.coords.latitude;
    var lng=position.coords.longitude;
    document.cookie="lat=" + lat;
    document.cookie="lng=" + lng;
    //var allcookies = document.cookie;
    //alert(allcookies);
    localStorage.setItem('latLng',latLng);
}
```

and in model i try to get cookie

```
$lat = Cookie::get('lat');
$lng = Cookie::get('lng');
dd($lat);
```

but it shows me null.
Any help please.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Laravel stores cookies encrypted, so `Cookie::get()` will only retrieve cookies set by Laravel. You should use the native `$_COOKIE['lat']` in PHP to retrieve cookies set for example in JavaScript.

You can find out more here:

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#cookies

Comment: Thanks .That statement is exact what i was looking for.
Got cookie value.